# question linear algebra notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve an exercise: if $A,B$ are $n\times n$ real matrices with $[A,B]=0$ then $\exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B)$. Now what could $[A,B]=0$ mean? I don't find this notation anywhere else.

Comment: In order for $\exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B)$ for matrices $A,B$ to be true you need $A$ and $B$ to commute. Otherwise the claim is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually $[A,B]=AB-BA$, so $[A,B]=0$ if and only if the matrices commute (i.e. $AB=BA$).

The reason (if you're interested) is that $[-,-]$ is the normal notation for the Lie bracket of a Lie algebra, and the set of $n\times n$ real matrices together with the operation $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is an example of such an algebra.